# How to sort Map by Key, but with two conditions in Java?

Tags: java, сортировка

У меня есть проблема в сортировке Map.
Имеется LinkedHashMap с ключами типа "September-2018", "October-2018", "November-2017", "November-2018".

Мне нужно отсортировать их:
"November-2017"
"September-2018"
"October-2018"
"November-2018"

Сначала по году, затем по месяцам. Как это реализовать? 
Когда я выполняю простую сортировку, то она идет по месяцам.
У меня была идея делать substring годов и потом сравнивать, но что-то пошло не так. 
Буду рад помощи.

```
`Map<String, String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    testMap.put("November-2018", "3");
    testMap.put("September-2018", "5");
    testMap.put("November-2017", "2");
    testMap.put("October-2018", "4");`
```

Тут я пытаюсь сравнивать по году

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class YearCompare implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int tempIntOne = Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(o1.length() - 3));
        int tempIntTwo = Integer.parseInt(o2.substring(o1.length() - 3));
        if (tempIntOne > tempIntTwo) {
            return 1;
        } else if (tempIntOne < tempIntTwo) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно показать код. Идея с разделением ключа на 2 части верная, кроме этого нужно правильное сравнение месяцев по имени.

Comment: Код покажите, который привел к проблеме.

Comment: Собственно кода как такового нет. Это мне просто задание дали. Изначально я думал через .thenCompaing два компаратора использовать, но чтото пошло не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю следующий подход:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy"); //устанавливаем формат даты, который Вы предлагаете (Месяц-год)
    Date date = sdf.parse(o1); //переводим в Date формат
    Date date2 = sdf.parse(o2);
    return date1.compareTo(date2); //вернет 1 если `data1 идет после date2 и -1 если наоборот.
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы отсортировать строки по дате достаточно преобразовать их в какой-нибудь класс, представляющий дату или время. Обычно эти классы уже реализуют интерфейс `Comparable` и не нужно придумывать сложную логику как сравнить November и December. В данном случае у нас есть только год и месяц, поэтому идеально подойдет `YearMonth`, чтобы не использовать устаревший `Date`.

- Перенесите ключи карты в новую коллекцию, реализующую интерфейс `List`, например `ArrayList`.
- Отсортируйте список используя сравнение не строк, а объектов `YearMonth`.
- Если нужно - сделайте новую карту по отсортированным ключам.

**З.Ы.** для правильного парсинга не забудьте указать нужную  `Local`

```
    Map<String, String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    testMap.put("November-2018", "3");
    testMap.put("September-2018", "5");
    testMap.put("November-2017", "2");
    testMap.put("October-2018", "4");

    // карта до сортировки
    System.out.println(testMap);
    System.out.println();

    // список с ключами
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(testMap.keySet());
    // сортировка компаратором
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH); // формат даты
            YearMonth ym1 = YearMonth.parse(o1, dateTimeFormatter); // парсинг
            YearMonth ym2 = YearMonth.parse(o2, dateTimeFormatter); // парсинг
            return ym1.compareTo(ym2); // сравнение встроенным Comparable
        }
    });

    // отсортированный список
    System.out.println(list);
    Map<String, String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String key : list){
        sortedMap.put(key, testMap.get(key));
    }

    // отсортированная карта
    System.out.println(sortedMap);
```